# Children's picture puzzle book, got a kid trying to avoid traps from dying

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, childrens-novel

I remember reading this book in the 3rd grade or something, and it had a kid going back through time or going through dimensions. He's trying to go back to his Grandfather or uncle's house, and the entire book is just a puzzle book. The puzzles consist of I think where he has to jump to pillar to pillar, trying to avoiding from falling on spikes (it's like a bird eyes view I think). People try to kill him throughout, and I think I saw that they were from medieval times or something. He may or may not have a dog or cat. Also don't say it's some book with a boy named Tom, I think his name was David or Daniel or something.

Comment: Do you remember how the puzzles were solved? Was it by trial and error? Entering choices into a chart? Logical deduction? And what do you mean by "some book with a boy named Tom"? Do you know a book that this is not?